# What are the advantages of storing date in database as an ISODate as opposed to a simple text?

Tags: mongodb, datetime, isodate, database

Why would I want to store as ISODate as opposed to simple text?

Answer (score 6):

[`ISODate`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#date) in MongoDB is just a function that provides a friendly wrapper for the usual JavaScript [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor. When you say this in MongoDB:

```
ISODate('2011-11-05T18:33:25Z')
```

You're saying the same thing as:

```
new Date(1320518005000);
```

but a human can read an [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO8601) date a lot easier than they can read the number of milliseconds since January 1 1970.

So, using `ISODate` gives you a real Date object in the database that you can call methods on (such as [`getMonth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth)) while also being able to easily eye ball its value. If you used a string for the date, then you'd be parsing strings all the time when you had to work with your dates. An example would be doing a [map/reduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/map-reduce/) to aggregate monthly data; you could parse the strings to extract the month but why bother with that when you can use a real date object that knows what months are?

Comment: that was an amazing answer. thank you for the detail. I have googled this for days and I have not gotten my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this source](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/iso-date):

> There are so many formats available, most of them incompatible with
>   others, that it can be a usability nightmare to choose a date
>   representation when writing for an international, cross-cultural
>   audience, as is the case on the web. Fortunately, there is one
>   solution in the ISO-developed international date format.